# How to upgrade existing GTM account to Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

What is the exact process of upgrading an existing google tag manager implementation to universal analytics? I am referring to changes I need to make in Google Tag Manager after upgrading within Google Analytics admin interface. I am getting myself confused with a few things :

1. For all existing tags with "Classic Google Analytics" tag type, do I simply change to Universal tag type or do I create a new universal tag type and replicate what I had in the classic tag? If i just need to switch the type, does anything else in the tag configuration change? or everything else stays the same?
2. After making all the changes, do i simply republish ? Or do i need to replace the tag manager snippet on my website with a new universal analytics version?
3. I am assuming there is no need to setup a new container and replicate everything i have in the old container?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just change an existing GA tag (i just tried) - if you do all configuration settings are lost. So you have to create new Universal Analytics Tags (makes sense, too, since the configuration options are different).

After that you remove your old Analytics tags, create a version and publish. No changes to the tag management code snippet are necessary and you do not need to replicate the container (that would pretty much defeat the purpose of a tag manager).

Comment: So the only changes required will be on the "classic google analytics" tag type?  Macros, rules and anything else will stay the same? I don't have any custom dimensions.  Also, what specific configuration items are different between the classic tag type and universal tag type?

Comment: Macros and rules will stay the same. Loss of configuration when you change the type on an existing tag includes the Account ID, so basically it's like starting over. If you are just tracking pageviews there is no other configuration, but for the differences between classic GA und UA you should simply expand the "more settings" pane (there is a lot more stuff in UA, Cross Domain Trackung is different etc.).